# Convert NumPy array to Python list

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How do I convert a [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array into a Python List?

Answer (score 585, accepted):

Use [`tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Note that this converts the values from whatever numpy type they may have (e.g. np.int32 or np.float32) to the "nearest compatible Python type" (in a list). If you want to preserve the numpy data types, you could call list() on your array instead, and you'll end up with a list of [numpy scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html). (Thanks to Mr_and_Mrs_D for pointing that out in a comment.)

Comment: If your list is float32 `tolist` will convert it to `floats`s - that's not desired probably. Using `list(myarray)` doesn't suffer from this - why should we prefer `tolist` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D are you suggesting that, despite having floats in your array, you'd like to have the resulting list be integers? That's sort of a whole different question... and of course you'd have to specify that despite being float32 values, they're all going to be integral. Anyway, if you had that situation, I guess doing `myarray.astype(np.int32).tolist()` would be an option, and explicit about what you're trying to accomplish. (And lastly, `list(array_of_type_float32)` doesn't give integers here when I tried it... so I don't know what you're asking.)

Comment: I never mentioned integers - try `float32_array = np.array([0.51764709], np.float32); print(float32_array.tolist()); print(list(float32_array))`

Comment: Okay, so the one converts to [float] and the other uses the numpy scalar float32 type still, as [np.float32]. Fine. Good to know, but I guess whether it's desirable or not depends on each specific case. For what it's worth, I suspect that generally when someone (like the OP) asks for conversion to a list, they implicitly mean a list of regular Python data types, in this case either floats or integers, and not a list of numpy scalar types. Thanks for pointing this out: I've edited the answer to include a note about that.

Comment: Along those lines:  `np.array([[0, 'one'], ['two', 3]]).tolist() -> [['0', 'one'], ['two', '3']]`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D To answer above question, we should prefer `tolist` when we want to serialize the data to json or yaml file.

Answer (score 19):

```
c = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

list(c.flatten())
```

Answer (score 17):

The numpy .tolist method produces nested lists if the numpy array shape is 2D.

if flat lists are desired, the method below works.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print type(a), len(a), a
npa = np.asarray(a)
print type(npa), npa.shape, "\n", npa
npa = npa.reshape((3, 3))
print type(npa), npa.shape, "\n", npa
a = list(chain.from_iterable(npa))
print type(a), len(a), a`
```

Comment: to get a flat list, there is also `a.flatten().tolist()` (or `list(a.flatten())` cf discussion above)

Comment: @ClementWalter Thanks! That comment is worth much more than the answer itself. Do you happen to know why .tolist() creates a nested list? Why do we have to go through so many steps to get a simple list? What's the rationale?

Comment: @deps_stats this is because `np.array(arr.tolist()) == arr`; in other words `.tolist` is sort of a serialization of `arr`

Answer (score 9):

`tolist()` works fine even if encountered a nested array, say a pandas `DataFrame`;

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0]
my_dt = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
new_list = [i[0] for i in my_dt.values.tolist()]

print(type(my_list),type(my_dt),type(new_list))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option

```
c = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

c.ravel()
#>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

# or
c.ravel().tolist()
#>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

also works.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to convert array to a list is using the numpy package:

```
import numpy as np
#2d array to list
2d_array = np.array([[1,2,3],[8,9,10]])
2d_list = 2d_array.tolist()
```

To check the data type, you can use the following:

```
type(object)
```