# How to convert list of numpy.ndarray to a list of lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list as follows( list of numpy.ndarray).

```
[array([207.48,   280.98,   227.55,   205.99,   896.99,
         218.75,   220.98,   415.88,], dtype=float64), array([  205.99,   363.25,   208.16,   500.98,   218.08,   320.98,
         296.18,   207.48,   280.98,   227.55,   205.99,   896.99,
         218.75,   220.98,   415.88,   699.99,  1360.14,   420.98,
         315.98,   449.99,   276.2 ,   370.98,   328.14,   276.2 ,
         296.18,   535.64,   399.98,   294.62,   500.98,   363.25])]
```

Now I need to convert to a list of lists as follows.

```
[[207.48,   280.98,   227.55,   205.99,   896.99,
             218.75,   220.98,   415.88,], [  205.99,   363.25,   208.16,  500.98,   218.08,   320.98,296.18,   207.48,   280.98,   227.55,   205.99,   896.99,218.75,   220.98,   415.88,   699.99,  1360.14,   420.98,               315.98,   449.99,   276.2 ,   370.98,   328.14,   276.2 ,                 296.18,   535.64,   399.98,   294.62,   500.98,   363.25]]
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure) but it didn't give expected result. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure' this didn't give the expected result

Comment: if your original list of arrays is `a`, you need to call `.tolist` on each element of your array: `[i.tolist() for i in a]`

Comment: What did you try, and what was the result wrong?

Comment: @tom Thank you very much  It gave what I was expected. Please put your comment as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: I can't because the question has already been closed... but glad you have a solution to your problem

Comment: @tom   I didn't close the question.Can't you put it as an answer?

Comment: No, it was closed as a duplicate