# Check for equal lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, types, scikit-learn

After reading this [Converting NumPy array into Python List structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure), I have:

```
import numpy as np
print np.array(centroids).tolist()
print "here\n"
print old_centroids

print type(np.array(centroids).tolist())
print type(old_centroids)
```

which gives:

```
[[-0.30485176069166947, -0.2874083792427779, 0.0677763505876472], ...,[0.09384637511656496, -0.015282322735474268, -0.05854574606104108]]
here
[array([-0.30485176, -0.28740838,  0.06777635]), ..., array([-0.03415291, -0.10915068,  0.07733185]), array([ 0.09384638, -0.01528232, -0.05854575])]
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
```

However, when I am doing:

```
return old_centroids == np.array(centroids).tolist()
```

I am getting this *Error*:

```
return old_centroids == np.array(centroids).tolist()
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
```

How to fix this?

The type of `centroids` is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and they are computed like this:

```
from sklearn import decomposition
centroids = pca.transform(mean_centroids)
```

---

Note, that without PCA, I would just do:

```
return old_centroids == centroids
```

---

EDIT_0:

[Check if two unordered lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal) suggests `set()`, thus I did:

```
return set(old_centroids) == set(np.array(centroids).tolist()) # or set(centroids)
```

and got:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing floating-point values it is better to use [`numpy.allclose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) and, consequently, keep your values in the `numpy` array form:

```
return np.allclose(np.array(old_centroids), np.array(centroids))
```

(notice that I transformed a list of 1D arrays to a 2D array; technically, you can apply `allclose()` separately for each pair of elements from `old_centroids` and `centroids`, if you wish.)

*Edit (based on the comment):* if `old_centroids` and `centroids` may have different shapes, check it before `allclose()`:

```
old = np.array(old_centroids)
new = np.array(centroids)
return old.shape == new.shape and np.allclose(old, new)
```

Comment: `r = all(less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y)))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25,0) (25,3)`. Is it maybe because at the very first time, `old_centroids` is just a list of 25 empty lists?

Comment: Well, it is certainly _not_ filled with empty lists in the printout you have in your question. Please add an executable example if there are other variants of `old_centroids` contents. If that is the only other variant, just check for array size to be greater than 0 before comparing.

Comment: fjarri, it will be too long and my question is already big. `old_centroids` consists of 25 empty lists at the very first iteration **only** and then gets as the one you see in my question, can't we bypass this? With a dummy check maybe before calling `allclose()`?