# For loop for an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I have the array `vAgarch` and I am trying to extract each element from that, so I have the following code now:

```
vAgarch = [0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04]
vAgarch = np.array(vAgarch)

# Extract each element from array vAgarch
dA1garch = np.fabs(vAgarch[0])
dA2garch = np.fabs(vAgarch[1])
dA3garch = np.fabs(vAgarch[2])
dA4garch = np.fabs(vAgarch[3])
dA5garch = np.fabs(vAgarch[4])
dA6garch = np.fabs(vAgarch[5])
```

However, this could be easier right? My array will consist of 40 elements later on and I think this code can be simplified with a for loop. I tried several for loops, but so far I have no success. Is there someone who can help me with simplifying this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you want everything in a standalone variable? I may be missing your point, but I'll propose something else if I'm understanding what you want.

As Jayhello mentioned, you can supply your original numpy array to `np.fabs()` directly. You stated in a comment that you did not want a list as you wanted to put these values in another list as well, but this is also possible with lists, using `np.append()`. Let's say the array that you want to add them to is `master_array`, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# other code here

new_arr = np.fabs(vAgarch)
master_array = np.append(master_array, new_arr)
```

This will append each of the elements from the vAgarch list to the other list after calling `fabs()` on them. If you'd like to add specific elements of the array only, you can just reference them by index (i.e. `new_arr[2]`) rather than creating separate variables for every single element.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a loop if you don't use separate variable names for dAgarch.

```
vAgarch= [0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04]
dAgarch=np.zeros(vAgarch.size)
vAgarch= np.array(vAgarch)

# Extract each element from array vAgarch
count =0
while(count<dAgarch.size):
    dAgarch[count]= np.fabs(vAgarch[count])
    count+=1
```

Or as you ask for loop

```
for count in range(0,dAgarch.size):
    dAgarch[count]= np.fabs(vAgarch[count])
```

Comment: Great thank you!! However, is it also possible to return the elements of vAgarch as single floats and not in array? Because now they are returned in an array and I need the elements as a stand-alone basis so I can put them into a list?

Comment: This question might have what you are looking for: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure) However, I suggest you read more about arrays and lists in python first.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake. because actually I don't want them in a list, I just want them on a stand-alone basis, so that I can add them to another array..

Comment: Quick note- python does not have the ++ operator. You can change `count++` to `count+=1`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a for loop，`numpy fabs` parameters can be `array_like`, so you can just pass list to it. As below code(I have change some elements in `vAgarch` to  minus):

```
def test_s():
    vAgarch = [-0.05, 0.03, -0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04]
    print vAgarch
    # [-0.05, 0.03, -0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04]

    # equivalent to a for loop
    arr2 = np.fabs(vAgarch)
    print arr2   # arr2 is a new array, all its elements is plus
    # [ 0.05  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.03  0.04]

    print vAgarch[0]
    # -0.05
    print arr2[0]
    # 0.05
```

you can also see tutorial in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fabs.html.

Or if you use pycharm,you can go to the function definition for example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
arr = np.fabs(vAgarch)
```

is enough.
In numpy almost all the function parameter can be `array_like`(list or numpy array), and returns array.

So there is no need to use for loop.I recommend you to learn more about numpy array operation.