# Masking nested array with value at index with a second array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a nested array with some values. I have another array, where the length of both arrays are equal. I'd like to get an output, where I have a nested array of `1`'s and `0`'s, such that it is `1` where the value in the second array was equal to the value in that nested array.

I've taken a look on existing stack overflow questions but have been unable to construct an answer.

```
masks_list = []
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    mask = (y_pred[i] == y_test.values[i]) * 1
    masks_list.append(mask)
masks = np.array(masks_list);
```

Essentially, that's the code I currently have and it works, but I think that it's probably not the most effecient way of doing it.

```
YPRED:
[[4 0 1 2 3 5 6]
 [0 1 2 3 5 6 4]]

YTEST:
8    1
5    4

Masks:
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: Could you give some test array and inner test array? If it's work it gonna be a good solution. I think you can done it also with map.

Comment: Post a sample of you desired I/O?

Comment: Added some example I/O.

Comment: So by 'nested array' you mean a 2d array (in your example shape (2,7)).

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good solution with less line of code.

```
a = set(y_pred).intersection(y_test)
f = [1 if i in a else 0 for i, j in enumerate(y_pred)]
```

After that you can check performance like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34806005/4510954) as follow:

```
import time
from time import perf_counter as pc

t0=pc()    
a = set(y_pred).intersection(y_test)
f = [1 if i in a else 0 for i, j in enumerate(y_pred)]
t1 = pc() - t0

t0=pc()
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    mask = (y_pred[i] == y_test[i]) * 1
    masks_list.append(mask)
t2 = pc() - t0

val = t1 - t2
```

Generally it means if value is positive than the first solution are slower.
If you have np.array instead of list you can try do as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966210/4510954):

```
type(y_pred)
>> numpy.ndarray
y_pred = y_pred.tolist()
type(y_pred)
>> list
```

Comment: np.array is unhashable.

Comment: Is this comment according to my answer or to @Jaja ?

Comment: Your comment, at this line: `a = set(y_pred).intersection(y_test)`

Comment: I understand that you have got np.array instead of list. Could you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966210/4510954

Answer (score 0):

Idea(least loop): compare array and nested array:

```
masks = np.equal(y_pred, y_test.values)
```

you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise) too:

```
np.array_equal(A,B)  # test if same shape, same elements values
np.array_equiv(A,B)  # test if broadcastable shape, same elements values
np.allclose(A,B,...) # test if same shape, elements have close enough values
```