# Array to list python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I need to convert numpy array in to a list

```
[ [1.        ] [0.89361702] [0.4893617 ] [0.44680851] [0.0212766 ] [0.        ] ]
```

this to

```
[ 1 ,0.89361702, 0.4893617,  0.44680851 ,0.0212766 ,0]
```

But when i use

```
duration= du.tolist()
```

duration looks like this

```
[[1.0],
[0.8936170212765937],
[0.4893617021276597],
[0.4468085106382951],
[0.02127659574468055],
[0.0]]
```

Please ignore the numbe of decimal points

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting NumPy array into Python List structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `du.reshape(-1).tolist()`. [`reshape(-1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) returns a view (whenever possible) of the flattened array, so it minimizes the overhead as compared to `flatten` that creates a copy.

Comment: _"ravel returns a view (whenever possible) ..."_ Not true. For example: `x = np.eye(4).T[0]` `np.shares_memory(x,x.ravel())` returns `False` whereas `np.shares_memory(x,x.reshape(-1))` returns `True`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer It is does it whenever it can, but unfortunately, in your case, it doesn't. From the `ravel` documentation, it mentions "When a view is desired in as many cases as possible, arr.reshape(-1) may be preferable.". Thanks for your comment, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised nobody suggested the `flatten` method from `numpy` [(doc)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.flatten.html). It's mostly the same as the `ravel` method suggested by @Gilles-Philippe Paillé.

One example:

```
import numpy as np

data = [[1.0],
        [0.89361702],
        [0.4893617],
        [0.44680851],
        [0.0212766],
        [0.0],]
array = np.array(data, dtype=float)

my_list= array.flatten().tolist()

print(my_list)
# [1.0, 0.89361702, 0.4893617, 0.44680851, 0.0212766, 0.0]
```

Comment: `flatten` is like `ravel` except it always makes a copy.

Answer (score 1):

very simple:

```
[ls[0] for ls in arr]
```

*I Hope this helps*

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way.

```
dura = [[1.0],
[0.8936170212765937],
[0.4893617021276597],
[0.4468085106382951],
[0.02127659574468055],
[0.0]]
new = []
for x in dura:
    if len(x)== 1:
        new.append(x[0])
```

and got this when printing new

```
[1.0, 0.8936170212765937, 0.4893617021276597, 0.4468085106382951, 0.02127659574468055, 0.0]
```

Comment: `1.0` requested to be `1`