# covert ndarray to list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list like this. Please pardon me if the title of the question is incorrect.

```py
[array(['5029339601'], dtype=object), array(['5029339601'], dtype=object)]
```

I would like to convert this one to a normal list like

```py
[ '5029339601' '5029339601']
```

I am sorry in advance for such a vague question. I would be grateful for your suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting NumPy array into Python List structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure)

Comment: I assume you're using NumPy, so I added the [tag:numpy] tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays have [`.tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method for that

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array('5029339601', dtype=object)
arr2 = np.array('5029339602', dtype=object)
lst = [arr1, arr2]
print(lst)

newlist = [item.tolist() for item in lst]
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy array's [tolist() method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy.ndarray.tolist) will get you nested lists.
There are a couple options for flattening lists.  If the depth is consistent, you can flatten it with something like [this](https://coderwall.com/p/rcmaea/flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-one-line-in-python).  If the depth is *not* consistent, or not know in advance, you'll need to do some sort of recursive flattening.